# ros python creating strange side effects

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- Ubuntu 16.04
- ROS Kinetic

I have been working on a program in python. Created my package just like I always do. This time I thought I would give dynamic reconfigure a try. I did the tutorial and ran the code. I wind up with my mouse turning into a cross, the libraries I import become files in the directory I launched from and the path name in my bash prompt changes.  Has anyone ever seen this before?

I can't get a screenshot of what happens to the pointer as it is not saved in screenshots.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257545/ros-python-creating-strange-side-effects/) by [sonyccd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25477/sonyccd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2017-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you post the top part of the script you ran? I bet you forgot to add a `#! /usr/bin/python` or similar to the top of your file.

If you have an executable file asd.py like

```
import numpy
a = 1
...
```

and do an './asd.py', Ubuntu will assume a bash-script (as there is no [shebang](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang)) Now the first command is 'import' which can be used to make partial screenshots: [import (bash)](https://ss64.com/bash/import.html). This is also the reason why your mouse pointer changes. (just type 'import asd.png' and mark a region) This also explains the new files (it's just the images (most probably postscript files)).

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sonyccd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25477/sonyccd/) on 2017-03-21**:
This is why you don't make a template generator, if your template is wrong alllll the auto created files will be wrong.

That was it, I did not add it on my ROS templates.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-03-21**:
which file did you run? Could you add it to your question?